# Is the set of integers locally compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, locally-compact-groups

I know $\mathbb{Q}$ is not locally compact as all compact subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ have empty interior.

Can I use the same argument to show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not locally compact?

All spaces are with usual toplogies.

Comment: Every point of $\mathbb{Z}$ has a compact neighbourhood.

Comment: @copper.hat which is the point itself, right?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ can also be locally compact. It depends on which topology you give it.

Comment: @math_for_ever Correct.

Comment: The usual topology on $\Bbb Z$ is discrete . Every subset is open, so every subset is its own interior, so the only subset with empty interior is the empty set.